# Text with bold and without in line with php word

Tags: php, laravel

I am beginner php developer. I have project in Laravel and https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord.

It's work fine. I have small problem.

This is my code:

```
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
        $section = $phpWord->addSection(
            array('orientation' => 'landscape', 'marginLeft' => 800, 'marginRight' => 800,'marginTop' => 700, 'marginBottom' => 700)
        );

        $footerFont = array('size' => 6, 'bold' => false, 'color'=>'black');
        $footer = $section->addFooter();
        $footer->addPreserveText(' Strona {PAGE} z {NUMPAGES} - Symfonia Smaków. Wszystkie prawa zastrzeżone. Data wydruku: '.date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), $footerFont);

        $header = $section->addHeader();
        $header->addImage($logo, array('width'=>50, 'height'=>40, 'align'=>'right'));

        $section->addTextBreak(4);
$summaryFont = array('size' => 8, 'bold' => true);
$section->addText("* alergeny zostały oznaczone wytłuszczoną czcionką.", $summaryFont, array('align' => 'left'));
```

In text: * alergeny zostały oznaczone wytłuszczoną czcionką. - i need add bold:

`* alergeny zostały oznaczone <b>wytłuszczoną</b> czcionką.`

How can I make it?

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the 1st page of README.md

Adding Text element with font customized using explicitly created font style object...

```
$fontStyle = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Font();
$fontStyle->setBold(true);
$fontStyle->setName('Tahoma');
$fontStyle->setSize(13);
$myTextElement = $section->addText('"Believe you can and you\'re halfway there." (Theodor Roosevelt)');
$myTextElement->setFontStyle($fontStyle);
```

Adding Text element with font customized using named font style...

```
$fontStyleName = 'oneUserDefinedStyle';
$phpWord->addFontStyle(
    $fontStyleName,
    array('name' => 'Tahoma', 'size' => 10, 'color' => '1B2232', 'bold' => true)
);
$section->addText(
    '"The greatest accomplishment is not in never falling, '
        . 'but in rising again after you fall." '
        . '(Vince Lombardi)',
    $fontStyleName
);
```

Comment: normally we don't translate OPs, but since the remaining of the answer is in English... Please in future make sure your question/answer is in English, which is the official language of this site. Thank you very much. See 

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/2275490